# Where to declare a default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

Is there any difference where (e.g. in a header or in a source file) to declare a default constructor? I mean, is there any difference in time execution performance in these cases?

That is, should

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
  A();
};
```

and

```
// A.cpp
A::A() = default;
```

work faster/slower/same time than

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
  A() = default;
};
```

Comment: it does make a difference but not for performance

Comment: why do you expect a significant performance difference between a constructor that does nothing and a constructor that does nothing?

Comment: Maybe there will be different constructor calls generated or some optimizations may be turned on, if a header already contains default ctor definition?

Comment: Aside from the existing answer, the one defined in the class is implicitly inline, whereas the other one is not, which *might* make a difference in the compiler's decision to actually inline the constructor.

Comment: Compilers do their best to optimise when allowed, but sometimes can fail. So if you profiled performance difference then you need to show compiler versions and compiling options. Otherwise we can't answer.

Comment: I think you're confusing declaration with definition.

Comment: Depending on fields of class it can have impact on forward declarations and as a result build times. Note is [highly recommended for destructors](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#making-the-compilation-faster).